# AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'onscreenclick'

Tags: python-3.x

This code has error..

I've tried on onscreenclick, onkeypress, and ontimer

```
c = turtle.Turtle('arrow'); c.color('black'); c.shapesize(csize); 
c.penup()
c.speed(5);

c.onscreenclick(c.goto)
c.listen()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
c.onscreenclick(c.goto)
c.listen()
```

Try

```
turtle.onscreenclick(c.goto)
turtle.listen()
```

Comment: Thank you! you're genius